# Populating ComboBox with JAVA FX MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I need to populate JAVAFX ComboBox with value using an MVC but somehow i cant get the combobox to work. Please help me,,

LoginController.java

```
package weltes.finance.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

/**
 * Created by engineering09 on 12/18/2015.
 */
public class LoginController {

    @FXML private ComboBox userComboBox;

    @FXML private void fillComboBox(){
        userComboBox.getItems().addAll("Item1", "Item2");
    }
}
```

loginscreen.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="163.0" prefWidth="357.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="weltes.finance.controller.LoginController">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="userComboBox" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="328.0" promptText="Select Registered User" />
      <PasswordField layoutX="15.0" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="328.0" promptText="Enter Password" />
      <Button layoutX="15.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="328.0" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It seems that your method `fillComboBox()` is never called. Moreover, your controller should implements `Initializable` so you can fill your ComboBox programmatically if desired in the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First list the items in the FXML.

```
   <ComboBox fx:id="userComboBox" editable="false" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#setTimeMultiplier">
  <items>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
      <String fx:value="Item 1" />
      <String fx:value="Item 2" />
      <String fx:value="Item 3" />
    </FXCollections>
  </items>
</ComboBox>
```

Then add or remove items from the ObservableArrayList.

```
userComboBox.getItems().removeAll(comboTime.getItems());
userComboBox.getItems().addAll(...);
```